# "How can I efficiently sort a list of custom objects in C# based on multiple properties?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, sorting, simultaneous

I have a list of custom objects in C#, and I need to sort this list based on multiple properties of the objects. Each object has several properties, and I want to sort the list first by `PropertyA` in ascending order and then by `PropertyB` in descending order. What's the most efficient and clean way to achieve this in C#?

Thank you!

I've tried using `List.Sort()` and `OrderBy()` with LINQ, but I'm having trouble sorting by multiple properties simultaneously. Can someone provide a code example or point me in the right direction to achieve this sorting efficiently?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With LINQ you can use `OrderBy(Descending)` followed by `ThenBy(Descending)`.

[`Enumerable.ThenByDescending`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.thenbydescending?view=net-7.0):

> Performs a subsequent ordering of the elements in a sequence in descending order.

The following:

```
var sorted = myCollection
    .OrderBy(i => i.PropertyA)
    .ThenByDescending(i => i.PropertyB)
    .ToList();
```

Will sort the collection by `PropertyA` (ascending) then by `PropertyB` in descending order and put results into a new list.

Answer (score 2):

I would make your custom object implement `IComparable<MyCustomObject>` and then you could build your comparison logic directly into the object so that it sorts by PropertyA ascending and by PropertyB descending.

```cs
public int CompareTo(MyCustomObject other)
{
    // depending on if you want nulls at the beginning or end
    // you may want this to be 1 or -1 or you may want to throw if you aren't
    // allowing null
    if (other == null)
        return 1;

    var result = PropertyA.CompareTo(other.PropertyA);

    // the PropertyA values are not the same, so the sorting is determined
    // by PropertyA only
    if (result != 0)
        return result;

    // the PropertyA values are the same, so now sort by PropertyB descending.
    result = other.PropertyB.CompareTo(PropertyB);

    return result;
}
```

With that logic built in, then you can just do `MyList.Sort()` and it will sort based on your `IComparable<MyCustomObject>`

This should be more efficient than Linq solutions since the comparisons will be done in a single shot, but this may be kind of a weird solution if the sorting of this custom object isn't always going to be done as described in your `CompareTo` implementation, so if this is a unique one off sorting it may make more sense to use a Linq solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ThenBy after OrderBy. And don't forget to use .ToList() in the end.

```
var sortedList = listOfCustomObjects
.OrderBy(obj => obj.PropertyA)
.ThenBy(obj => obj.PropertyB)
.ToList();
```